# Any way to control the volume/mute for Caller ID announcement?

Tags: volume-control, ringtone, caller-id

I really like the "Caller ID announcement" feature, where it announces the number calling you.  However, I've noticed it announces it regardless of my volume or mute settings.  I do not want my phone making any noise if it's set to "Silent", or the ringer volume is all the way down.  Any way to do that?

[image]

I'm using Android 11 on a OnePlus 9 Pro running Oxygen OS 11.2.10.10.LE15AA.  Thanks!